# Submitting bug reports for Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, debugging

I come from Ubuntu and when things crashed I could collect the relevant information and submit a bug report. Is there an easy or preferred way to do this in Arch Linux after an application crashes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arch is a DIY distro: there is no automated tool for bug reporting. There is, however, [comprehensive guidance on the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reporting_Bug_Guidelines) for reporting bugs.

The philosophy of Arch, the [Arch Way](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/The_Arch_Way), stresses self-sufficiency and a willingness to contribute solutions, which means [actively participating in bug reporting and squashing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bug_Squashing_Day). This doesn't fit well with an automated <strike>complaint</strike> reporting system.